# How can i have pages with different image url?

Tags: html, css

I have a website template that includes 5 pages. At the top of the page, there is a photograph, which is controlled by the id tag #subheader. It has subsequent css for the text, etc.

```
    #subheader {
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  background: #222;
  background: url(file:///Users/Nineborn/Desktop/New%20LW%20Construction%20Site/Services.jpg)top fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#subheader h1 {
  color: #eceff3;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
#subheader span {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 88px;
  color: #fff;
}
#subheader .subdetail {
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #777;
  padding-left:0px !important;
}
#subheader .subdetail li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  margin:0;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
}
#subheader .subdetail li a {
  color: #ff6600;
}
#subheader .subdetail li.sep {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

The problem is, I want to have a different image for all the pages. How can i adjust my CSS so that I can have all the same properties, except different urls?

Comment: You need javascript or duplicates/subclasses of `#subheader` for every page.
So basically, for every page you would use a different clone/subclass of `#subheader` with just the background image changed.

For example: `#subheader.firstpage { background-image: <different_url>; }`

Comment: You know, thats exactly the first thing i tried. I just copy and pasted the whole thing, and changed the id tag name to #subheader2, for example. But then the text and image would be screwed up for the new tags. So im at a loss.

Comment: Yes, because you would have to also copy `#subheader span` etc.
See my answer, you can achieve this in a better way using classes

Comment: Could you give me a little more detail? Im having trouble grasping this. 

Youre saying create a new class for each page and add it to the html in addition to the subheader id tag? edit: woops just saw your answer below

Comment: No, I'm saying that it's a one way to do it - but it's not a good way.

I gave you a proper way in the answer.

Comment: ok but what about the fact that the url already exists in the #subheader tag? Do i delete the url there?

Comment: If you set ID to `subheader` then class to `first`, it'll inherit everything from subheader but then override properties that also exist in class `first` - example in the answer.

Comment: it doesnt display the url when i apply it

Answer (score 0):

Since the url will be page dependant, it makes sense to have that specific part of the CSS on the actual page and not on the general CSS file.

You can add a `style` tag on your page's HTML with the `background-image` property. I don't know if you are using some framework or anything, just take this idea.

On page 1:

```
<body>
  <style>
    #subheader {
      background-image: url('image_1.jpg');
    }
  </style>
  something something...
</body>
```

On page 2:

```
<body>
  <style>
    #subheader {
      background-image: url('image_2.jpg');
    }
  </style>
  something something...
</body>
```

You could have a default image on the CSS file if you want to have some fallback value.

Answer (score -1):

The only thing that you can do with plain CSS is to make a subclass for every page you want the different image to be on.

Here's how:

```
#subheader.first
{
    background: --url here;
}

#subheader.second
{
    background: --url here;
}
```

Then you apply it as such on different pages:

```
<div id="subheader" class"first">
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/bw5xdfrg/